# Is it the correct length vs. has it got the correct length

Tags: phrases

Which sounds more natural to a native speaker of English? "Is the code the correct length?" or "Has the code got the correct length"?

Speaking as a non-native language professional, I'd choose "is", but I've seen "has" version often enough to start wondering. Most Poles use "has" (mother tongue impact), and I suppose the same may be true for many other non-native speakers.

Do you have any strong preference towards any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely "is" and not " has". Someone *is* 6 feet tall, something is 600 cm long etc.

Its' definitely a case of language interference ( what you called " mother tongue impact").

Comment: ahhhh, language interference -- I wasn't sure if that was the correct term, so I used plain English. I'm wondering what other lgs apart from Slavic ones work this way.

Comment: It's a universal phenomenon, so it doesn't hinge on one's mother tongue. All bilinguals are subject to it to some degree.

Comment: I meant what other language groups interfere in the same way (is/has). From what I know of otther Slavic languages, describe qualities like dimension more like "has" rather than "is" hence frequent mistakes made in English (a very common "I have 15 years" mistake). Germanic languages seem to take a different approach. I'm wondering about other langauges. From what I remember, in Spanish you also say things like "tengo 40 anos".

Comment: That's right. Romance languages ( Italian, Spanish etc) also seem to operate in this "I have 15 years" way,  as opposed to I'm 15. Same for length and whatnot.  Beyond that, I couldn't say.